# How to parse a xml by ANT

Tags: xml, ant

trying to build a project set file and checkout these projects:

```
<psf>
  <project ref="version,url,name"/>
  <project ref="version,url,name"/>
  <project ref="version,url,name"/>
</psf>
```

now I need extract url and name from each project tag. I used

`<xmlproperty file="example.psf" collapseAttributes="true" />`

but when I

`<echo>$psf.project.ref</echo>`,

I got something like this, instead of having control to each token on each line:

`version,url,name,version,url,name,version,url,name`

Can someone help me with this? thanks

Answer (score 11):

I've used this http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/ in the past to process XML with ANT.  I threw together a quick sample of getting each individual attribute.

```
    <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
    <xmltask source="test.xml">
        <call path="psf/project">
            <param name="ref" path="@ref"/>
            <actions>
                <echo>ref = @{ref}</echo>
            </actions>
        </call>
    </xmltask>
```

Not sure if this will suit your needs, but it does work to get the attribute values individually.

Comment: @Tom then you should validate the answer