# Best way to view/edit a property file in Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, properties

I am trying to create a GUI tool to edit few property files, each property file contains large amount of lines. What's the best swing controls in Java should I use in order to load these property files.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't neglect to accept answers that [you found helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344295/how-to-parse-a-xml-by-ant/2344444#2344444).

Answer (score 3):

You could present an editable JTable with two columns, one for property key, one for property value

Comment: cool, thanks, I am trying to find some similar practice online, do you have any recommendation on using jTable?

Comment: Maybe http://www.javalobby.org/articles/jtable/ or http://www.builderau.com.au/program/java/soa/Keep-data-display-clean-with-JTable-class/0,339024620,320275793,00.htm

Answer (score 1):

http://zaval.org/products/jrc-editor/index.html
Take a look at this. It shows all keys in a tree like structure and let you edit them. Supports multiple locale dependent files and represent them accordingly.