# Using AndroidManifest.xml version code in ant

Tags: java, android, ant

Does anyone know if it's possible to get variables from the AndroidManifest.xml **for ant use**?

Specifically, I'm trying to get `versionCode`,`versionName`, and `packageName` out somehow.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Conclusion

It seems that this is too troublesome to do, and since this problem is easily solved with Maven I've given up on the possibility of a quick solution for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there is an android dedicated solution, which i dont know, but apart from that you can treat android manifest file as any other xml file -> so all you need is an ant task for parsing xml file and retrieving values from it.

as writing custom ant task in java is not a rocket science - there allready is something you could try to use.

see: [How to parse a xml by ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344295/how-to-parse-a-xml-by-ant)

so in your case it would be sth like (with use of http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/):

```
<target name="retrieveFromManifest" desciption="retrieveFromManifest">
    <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
    <xmltask source="${pathToAndroidManifestFile}">
        <copy path="/manifest/@android:versionCode" property="androidVersionCode"/>
        <copy path="/manifest/@android:versionName" property="androidVersionName"/>
        <copy path="/manifest/@package" property="androidPackage"/>
    </xmltask>
    <echo message="Version code: ${androidVersionCode}" />
    <echo message="Version name: ${androidVersionName}" />
    <echo message="package: ${androidPackage}" />
</target>
```

EDIT:

If you think about parsing this in your android project's build.xml then you have xpath task "out of the box". Any automatically generated build file for android project imports the global sdk's build file `<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />`, in which you have:

```
<taskdef name="xpath"
        classname="com.android.ant.XPathTask"
        classpathref="android.antlibs" />
```

And example usage some lines later:

```
<xpath input="AndroidManifest.xml" 
                expression="/manifest/application/@android:hasCode"
                output="manifest.hasCode" default="true"/>
```

Comment: If no one else responds, then I'll accept your answer. But I'd really like to be able to do it without an external jar file.

Comment: Guy, since there is neither xml parsing task nor regexp find task bundled directly with ant, I think it's not possible to do that with xml-syntax only and no external jar. 
When you do not want to include external jar, there is a possible (but ugly, imho) solution ;), then my hint is: see `<script>` or `<scriptdef>` ant tasks for usage with javascript/rhino or beanshell. If you were really interested in doing it "the khtulu way", and still didn't know how to, let me know i could provide some example.

Comment: Ps. Alternatively You could use `propertyregex` task from ant-contrib - but it still requires external jar, as the example above.

Comment: It just sounds like it's a pain in the butt to do, which probably means that it wasn't meant to be done. Also, this problem is easily solved with Maven. So whatever haha

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is not that hard:

```
<xmlproperty file="AndroidManifest.xml" prefix="mymanifest" collapseAttributes="true"/>
```

And you use it like this:

```
${mymanifest.manifest.android:versionName}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this parses the whole XML file and converts its all nodes and attributes into corresponding ant properties. In case your manifest is very big then it can be much overhead. :(