# Parse JUnit result XML format (created by 3rd party tool) with Maven

Tags: xml, maven, testing, integration-testing

I'm running a Maven build workflow which involves running a 3rd party tool for integration testing, which produces multiple XML files in JUnit style (however, those files are **not** created by JUnit and I have no control over the testing procedure).

Is there a Maven plugin, which allows me to parse those files? Especially, I would like the build to fail, in case those XML files list a failure.

My exact problem has been described [here](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/How-to-parse-JUnit-report-xml-that-causes-build-to-pass-fail-td5433750.html) some years ago, and the proposed solutions were:

1. *"Write your own plugin to call your external test and report failures, 
   either by parsing the xml or some other approach"* -- potential solution, however I hope that some years later maybe there is something ready-to-use?
2. *"Adjust your external test tool so it returns "false" (1) when it has a 
   failure which Maven should pick up and understand to mean "failure 
   encountered" and it will fail the build"* -- unfortunately, I have no control over the external tool.

Comment: Well you could use an Ant script that parses the XML ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2344295/1743880)) or write a plugin. Maven doesn't do that. But I'm not sure why you want to use Maven in the first place to parse this?

Comment: The reason why I need Maven to parse this, is that I want the build to fail, in case the integration test has errors. I can still do a fine grained parsing of the XML files through our CI system, but for local builds it's easy to overlook potential test failures. Currently the console lists SUCCESS, even though the integration test has failed.

Comment: Okay, well, as I said in my previous comment, Maven was not build for this task and I don't know any Maven plugins that would parse a XML file. I think Ant (and even with Ant I'm not sure if it's truly possible) or your own plugin is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, in case nobody comes up with a different solution, I'll try to write a simple plugin. https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/tree/master/surefire-report-parser looks helpful as foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody should ever encounter a similar problem, [here](https://github.com/qqilihq/maven-test-parser-plugin) is my solution in form of a Maven plugin.